# How to prevent the electron-packager from messing up the paths of the application?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

After I compiled the application with electron-packager the application expects files to be in the root folder of the application, whereas they are located in ./app/resources/

How can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

Does your code write to your local project?
You cannot write to your project folder if you package your app with asar.
I advice using appData as your file path.
Example: `%appdata%/YourProjectName/something.json`

Comment: No, but it seems to expect the files in the root folder of the app, whereas they are in ./app/resources/